# How to reuse a ThemeProvider with styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-context, yarn-workspaces

I use styled-components in a monorepo built with [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/). The folder structure is like this:

```
- packages
  - package-a
  - package-b
  - theme
```

In `theme`, I export a default `ThemeProvider` like this:

```js
const defaultTheme = { ... };

export default function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  return <StyledThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>{children}</StyledThemeProvider>;
}
```

This code gets transpiled with [@babel/preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react). The output is imported in `package-a` and `package-b` (both are create-react-app projects) and added as a top-level component.

but I'm getting this error when trying to reuse the theme in either of these two packages:

> index.js:1375 Component styled.div (.sc-fzXfNf) uses "props.theme" in its styles but no theme was provided via prop or ThemeProvider.

I logged the `props` and the `theme` object is empty ({}). Why is that? Is it even possible to do what I want here?

Comment: Note: I sorted this in the meantime by not creating the `ThemeProvider`  in the `theme` package and exporting only the theme object - later on, I create the provider components in every react app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was just mistakenly using different versions of React in the two packages. I sync-ed my dependencies, cleaned `node_modules` and now the code I wrote originally works fine:

```js
const defaultTheme = { ... };

export default function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  return <StyledThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>{children}</StyledThemeProvider>;
}
```

Note: this is within a yarn workspaces monorepo, not sure how this works with other tools.